# Search bar not working; column not found?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Ok. I am making a BIG program that should be released today but sadly i delayed because of this problem while testing. I have administration area to recover people informatio just in case and i noticed search bar dosen't work giving me a error that column is not working. I am using database MySql. Programming in vb.net. The error is: Cannot find column [nusername]. But it does exist. Everything works correctly. And yes i know about the sql injection ignore it. Here is my code but please don't steal my coding:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class DeathLairAdminControlPanel
    Dim MySqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim MySqlCmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim dbDT As New DataTable

    Public Property AUsernameHomePass As String
    Private Sub DeathLairAdminControlPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LabelALoggedIn.Text = AUsernameHomePass
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonUpdateU_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdateU.Click
        If TextBoxNUsern.Text = "" Or TextBoxNEmail.Text = "" Or TextBoxNPass.Text = "" Or TextBoxNPhone.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please don't leave empty areas.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf TextBoxNUsern.Text.Length < 4 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username too short.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf TextBoxNEmail.Text.Length < 8 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Email cant be that short. IT MUST BE VALID!.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf TextBoxNPass.Text.Length < 6 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Password can't be that short. Make it longer and secure.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf TextBoxNPhone.Text.Length < 6 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Phone number can't be that short. IT MUST BE VALID.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNUsern.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$") And System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPass.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9.]+$") And System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNEmail.Text, "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*") And System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNPhone.Text, "^\+[0-9()-+ ]+$") And System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBoxNCity.Text, "^[A-Za-z ]+$") Then

            MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
            MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
                "server=localhost;userid=root;password=HIDDEN;database=syscore"
            Dim MySqlRea As MySqlDataReader

            Try
                MySqlConn.Open()
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "update syscore.normaluser set nusername='" & TextBoxNUsern.Text & "',nemail='" & TextBoxNEmail.Text & "',npass='" & TextBoxNPass.Text & "',nphone='" & TextBoxNPhone.Text & "',ncity='" & TextBoxNCity.Text & "' where nusername='" & TextBoxNUsern.Text & "'"
                MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
                MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader

                MessageBox.Show("User has been updated.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                MySqlConn.Close()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                MySqlConn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End If
        loaddatabase_table()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDeleteU_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDeleteU.Click
            MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
            MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
                "server=localhost;userid=root;password=HIDDEN;database=syscore"
            Dim MySqlRea As MySqlDataReader

            Try
                MySqlConn.Open()
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "delete from syscore.normaluser where nusername'" & TextBoxNUsern.Text & "'"
                MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
                MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("User has been deleted.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                TextBoxNUsern.Text = ""
                TextBoxNEmail.Text = ""
                TextBoxNPass.Text = ""
                TextBoxNPhone.Text = ""
                TextBoxNCity.Text = ""
                MySqlConn.Close()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                MySqlConn.Dispose()
            End Try
        loaddatabase_table()
    End Sub

    Private Sub loaddatabase_table()
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=HIDDEN;database=syscore"
        Dim MySqlDAd As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource

        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from syscore.normaluser"
            MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            MySqlDAd.SelectCommand = MySqlCmd
            MySqlDAd.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            MySqlDAd.Update(dbDataSet)
            TextBoxNUsern.Text = ""
            TextBoxNEmail.Text = ""
            TextBoxNPass.Text = ""
            TextBoxNPhone.Text = ""
            TextBoxNCity.Text = ""
            MySqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonLDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonLDB.Click
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=HIDDEN;database=syscore"
        Dim MySqlDAd As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource

        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from syscore.normaluser"
            MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            MySqlDAd.SelectCommand = MySqlCmd
            MySqlDAd.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            MySqlDAd.Update(dbDataSet)
            TextBoxNUsern.Text = ""
            TextBoxNEmail.Text = ""
            TextBoxNPass.Text = ""
            TextBoxNPhone.Text = ""
            TextBoxNCity.Text = ""
            MySqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
        loaddatabase_table()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim gridrow As DataGridViewRow
            gridrow = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

            TextBoxNUsern.Text = gridrow.Cells("nusername").Value.ToString
            TextBoxNEmail.Text = gridrow.Cells("nemail").Value.ToString
            TextBoxNPass.Text = gridrow.Cells("npass").Value.ToString
            TextBoxNPhone.Text = gridrow.Cells("nphone").Value.ToString
            TextBoxNCity.Text = gridrow.Cells("ncity").Value.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxSdbgrid_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSdbgrid.TextChanged
        Dim DV As New DataView(dbDT)
       ' ERROR HERE:
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("nusername Like '%{0}%'", TextBoxSdbgrid.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReportToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MessageBox.Show("To get support or report do it on skype gangsteris33 we are always online until night.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoginToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Form1.Show()
        TextBoxNCity.Text = ""
        TextBoxNEmail.Text = ""
        TextBoxNPass.Text = ""
        TextBoxNPhone.Text = ""
        TextBoxNUsern.Text = ""
        TextBoxSdbgrid.Text = ""
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClearChat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClearChat.Click
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=HIDDEN;database=sysinfo"
        Dim MySqlRea As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "delete from syscore.normaluser"
            MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Chat has been cleaned.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            MySqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope you can fix it. I been trying to find the reason but no idea. Someone who can edit this please fix this bad code pasting. (website problem not my skill). If someone want to mark this as duplicate then please give me a fix using my code before you block this topic.

Comment: `where nusername'" & TextBoxNUsern.Text & "'"` Did you miss something here?

Comment: It's the delete command as @Steve has pointed out.

Comment: Don't post all of your code, only the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: And where do you fill the `DataTable dbDT`? The code above just use that variable asking to create a DataView then you try to apply the filter but there is nowhere in sight the filling of the `dbDT`

Comment: You are trying to set a filter in the TextChanged event which means the filter will be (re)set *every time* the user presses a key.  But the real problem is that you declare a new local DGV in that procedure - probably not what you want since that column wont exist in the brand new temp/local DGV

Comment: How is the delete working correctly; there's nothing that says where... for ex: '=' or LIKE... unless you are typing it in the textbox?

Comment: Thanks about the delete button. While checking why the search box not working i deleted it by accident. And i think i get it how to fix the search box. Still searching but i think i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the method `loaddatabase_table` add this line after the dataset fill

```
Private Sub loaddatabase_table()
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable ' This is a misleading name. 

    ....
    MySqlDAd.Fill(dbDataSet)
    ' Add this line
    dbDT = dbDataSet
End Sub
```

Now the global variable `dbDT` points to the effective table loaded from the db, so, when you build the DataView the column `nusername` is present in the source datatable

Note that the code in the delete button cannot work because you are missing the = between the `nusername` and the value to delete

Finally, while calling `ExecuteReader` works also for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query, the correct method to use is ExecuteNonQuery to avoid the unnecessary building of a DataReader when you have nothing to read from your command

Comment: Yess. This does work i can feel it but its getting me the error Error                Tables' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataTable' What do i need to write in Tables? i have only 1 table. normalusers.

Comment: What do i need to do? i getting error in the line i added.

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed that your dbDataSet is not a DataSet but directly a DataTable (misleading name), Just assing the dbDataSet to dbDT, fixing the answer now

Comment: YES. IT WORKS. THANKS!. And yea my buttons did not work but now they do.

Answer (score 0):

you should check your connection string or put an error message like this:

Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try